# Adjusting page height with css

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a way to adjust the height of the page in mobile view?

Tried:

```
 @media (max-width:768px). 
{body.page-id-3748 
{overflow:hidden;}}
```

This gets rid of the footer altogether, which I dont want.

Then tried:

```
 @media (max-width:768px). 
{body.page-id-3748 {width: 
20px; height: 20px;}}
```

This adjusted width but not height. Indeed when I tried just height nothing happened.

```
 @media (max-width:768px){body, html.page-id-3748 
{height: 50px;}}
```

Nothing.

Comment: Can you add a working example?

Comment: Can you share your code? @Fresh

Comment: can you show us screen show of what you have and what you want to achieve in case you can't supply with simple working examples